# Add/Update User field in ??.sharepoint.com

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

This issue only manifests on SharePoint online site.

I am able to do adds and updates to the list without issue **until** trying to update the user type Employee. Previously, for my on-prem customers I have added Id eg Employee**Id** to the user column *Employee* and passed the foreign key (userid) to the list containing the people type field with success.

Now on our online SP I get a failure when trying to update a user. *Error processing request stream. The request should be a valid top-level resource object.*

[image]

EDIT: single entries only;

[image]

When pulling the list item the JSON property for Employee is:

```
...
<content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
        <d:EmployeeId m:type="Edm.Int32">3642</d:EmployeeId>
...
```

Hard-coding the item properties using my userid of 31: (If I remove the EmployeeId this works)

```
var itemProperties = {
    EmployeeId : 31,
    CurrentProject: 'currentproject'
};

updateListItem(
    myWebUrl()
    , "DSRMB"
    , id
    , itemProperties
    , function (success) {
        console.log('item has been updated');
    }
    , function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
);
```

---

no magic here included just in case or TL;DR

```
function updateListItem(webUrl, listName, itemId, itemProperties, success, failure) {
    getListItemById(webUrl, listName, itemId, function (item) {

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: item.__metadata.uri,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": item.__metadata.etag
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties), 
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });

},
function (error) {
    failure(error);
});

}

function getListItemById(webUrl, listName, itemId, success, failure) {
    var url = webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName + "(" + itemId + ") ";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: gMMTasync,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            if (data.responseJSON) {
                if (listName !== "UserInformationList") {
                    failure(data.responseJSON.error);
                } else {
                    console.log("getListItemById No data returned for ID: " + itemId);
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the person column marked to allow multiple selections?  The format for setting a multi-user field is different than a single-user field.  Also, while is does still work, the listdata.svc is considered deprecated, you should really be using the [Items REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#update-list-item).

Comment: 'SinglePersonColumnId':9,  
'MultiPersonColumnId':{'results':[9,12]}}

Comment: Single entry only. Updated question

Comment: Are you certain that "Employee" is the **internal** name of the Field?  https://sympmarc.com/2009/12/11/staticname-versus-displayname-on-sharepoint-lists/